# Can I add a value to a vector without pushing it?

Tags: c++, vector, addition, assertion

Is there any way I can create a vector pair like this

```
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> myReg;
```

Then adding it like this:

```
  myReg[0].first = "title of the movie";
  myReg[0].second = 1968;
  myReg[1].first = "title of the 2nd movie";
  myReg[1].second = 2008;
```

As is it gives me a

> Debug assertion Failed

Without using this:

```
myReg.push_back(std::pair<std::string, int>("title of the movie", 1968));
```

Comment: i don't know why you are using pair instead of making a movie `class`

Comment: The aversion to `push_back` is because....?

Comment: FWIW you can make your `push_back` a bit nicer e.g. `myReg.push_back(std::make_pair("title of the movie", 1968));` or ``myReg.push_back({"title of the movie", 1968});``

Comment: I haven't programmed in years and have always used arrays and will take a bit of rethinking to use push_back. Though I might like the class idea. Hmmm I got to look up how to save the 2 items in a class to save and load from a file.

Comment: If you were using a `std::map` then simply indexing it via key `map[1]` would perform an automatic `::emplace()` so you wouldn't need to explicitly create the record.  But a map uses keys (which can be `int`) not indexes...

Comment: @MickeyD I don't really know what you mean when you say using push_back will require a rethink especially if you're accepting of `class` s. If you want to learn C++ then learn C++, no one uses the "C with classes cousin" and colleagues ull be non too impressed with ridiculous code like `myReg.resize(2); myReg[myReg.size()-1] = std::pair<std::string, int>("title of the movie", 1968);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the exact code snippet you've shown**, you must first do [`myReg.resize(2)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize):

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> myReg;
myReg.resize(2);
myReg[0].first = "title of the movie";
```

You could also change `std::vector<...> myReg;` to be [`myReg(2);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> myReg(2);
myReg[0].first = "title of the movie";
```

As mentioned in a comment, another option would be to use `std::map<>` instead of `vector<>`; this gives you the "auto expand" (no call to `push_back()`), but often isn't nearly as convenient as a `vector<>` since the memory isn't contiguous.  That code looks like

```
std::map<int, std::pair<std::string, int>> myReg;
myReg[0].first = "title of the movie";
```

You could also make your own vector-like class with an `operator []` (and `at()`) to automatically grow the vector; this quickly gets messy and will likely be frowned upon by your colleagues, but here's the (not necessarily recommended) idea:

```
template<typename T>
class my_vector
{
    std::vector<T> v;

public:
    T& operator[](size_t i) {
        if (i >= v.size())
            v.resize(i+1);
        return v[i];
    }

    // ... a lot of other methods copied from std::vector<> ...
};

my_vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> myReg;
myReg[0].first = "title of the movie";
```

Comment: ...so long as your contained type is default-constructible.

Comment: whay are you incrementing the size by **two** ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi to provide enough elements for the two elements mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks and I guess you are saying I have to know the size in order to do it this way.

Comment: Oh wait hmmm . I can resize it after I get each new value.  Though maybe it's not as nice as using the modern way of push_back and / or using classes instead.

Comment: You could also use the fill constructor, which can provide a default value if necessary.

Comment: @ebyrob. Oh that's interesting. Got any small example based on mine above?

Comment: @MickeyD Dan (the answerer) added it as his second example.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of initializer lists:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> myReg{
    {"title of the movie", 1968},
    {"title of the 2nd movie", 2008}
};
```

If you need to add more later, it's still simple:

```
myReg.push_back({"title 3", 2000});
myReg.emplace_back("title 4", 2001);
```

Comment: Hmmm yeah that will take some rethinking on my part. Not sure if that method is limited to the version of C++ compiler I'm using. MS Visual C++ 2010 in my case.  I know some syntax doesn't work with older versions.

Comment: @MickeyD -- Get a compiler that is at least compliant with C++ 11.  Visual Studio 2010 is not one of them.  If you don't then you'll be wasting your time when you get answers to your questions that use C++ 11 syntax (2011 was 6 years ago).

Comment: @MickeyD, You're already using part of C++11 with your vector by having `>>` right next to each other. IIRC, VS2010 supports a very small part of C++11, but not much. I would strongly recommend something like VS2015 Community as an upgrade - it's free, and VS2017 is out soon. Open source compilers like GCC and Clang are still an option on Windows as well, and on that note, Clang is shipped with Visual Studio nowadays.

Comment: Currently using a nice and small code::blocks IDE install on a small virtual image with the built in 2010 compiler support. Only upgrade I have seen for 2015 is this huge upgrade and I rarely program in C++. If you know of a way to just get the 2015 c++ basics without going through that huge install I'll throw another party :) Thanks

Comment: @MickeyD, While still fairly large (VS is a very big and bloated IDE), the 2017 installer (currently in RTM) has a lot more modularity, with C++ development being one of their predefined packs, though you can still fine-tune that. I can't recall if there's a way to install the command line tools without the IDE.

Comment: @chris. Thanks for the information. I will have to keep my eye out for 2017 if it's modular in the sense I can just install a very small portion of the studio.

Answer (score 0):

### You have 2 general ways:

First, you can use vector's constructor:

---

**vector (initializer_list il,
       const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());**

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> myReg(2);
myReg[0].first = "title of the movie";
myReg[0].second = 1968;
myReg[1].first = "title of the 2nd movie";
myReg[1].second = 2008;
```

**explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());**

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> myReg{
    {"title of the movie", 1968},
    {"title of the 2nd movie", 2008}
};
```

Or resize the vector before initiation:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> myReg;
myReg.resize(2)
myReg[0].first = "title of the movie";
myReg[0].second = 1968;
myReg[1].first = "title of the 2nd movie";
myReg[1].second = 2008;
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for everyone's help. Great people on here with lots of ideas.

OK this is from @Dan as one option though I'm looking into maybe using a class or @chris's method

```
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> myReg(1);

  myReg[0].first = "title of the movie";
  myReg[0].second = 1968;
  myReg.resize(2);
  myReg[1].first = "title of the 2nd movie";
  myReg[1].second = 2008;
```